# excela analysis between 2 different excel files

Tags: python, excel

[code not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwciL.jpg)

See image for reference. The code is not working it is breaking somewhere but I can't figure out wher. Can anyone help me? I've tried this approach using openpyxl and pandas, but no luck. I want to automate data refresh in the excel file.

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image, just edit your code into your question and format it as code (with the curly brackets {} option)